# textarea disable scroll by up/down arrows

Tags: html, css

I have textarea with overflow: hidden; style.
But, whenever I press on the up/down arrows, the textarea scrolls a bit.
Is there any way to disable this scroll?

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bV3W/

If you press up and down keys the text is moved.

```css
textarea {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 160px;
        height: 60px;
        font-size: 65px;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: inherit;
        display: block;
        font-family: inherit;
        line-height: 1;
        min-width: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        resize: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: pre;
    }
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="false" class="draggable"></textarea>
```

I can enlarge the height but in my case I can't. Is there any way to avoid this scroll?

Comment: make it `display:block;` or give it `width` and `height`
That's all the assumption I have over no code question

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: font size 65px in a 60px height? scroll will occur

Answer (score 1):

this is because font size is bigger than the height of your **textarea** when try to apply smaller font size, `font-size: 30px;` will works fine. except this your code is fine @Naor

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the textarea in a div wrapper, like so:

```
<div class="textarea_wrapper"><textarea spellcheck="false" class="draggable"></textarea></div>
```

Then, set the CSS of that wrapper to the CSS you had for the textarea, and for the textarea add a line-height equivalent to the height of the wrapper div:

```
.textarea_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 160px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 65px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 65px;
    line-height:60px;
    width: 160px;
}
```

[See this Fiddle for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/4spSS/)

Comment: What if I want two lines of text? How can I change this?

Comment: Just double the height of the wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/vCnrh/ (I also set a width on the textarea, forgot that in the other fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Well the question seems quite old but hope my code would help someone in need!!
There is no simple way to achieve this but yes it can be done, check [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharshuklaa/qL7ec058/).

What i've done is:
1. Fixing height of textarea
`height: 10rem;`
2. Say there are four rows, then line-height= height/4 (calculate it yourself as required)
3.Disable scrollbars
`overflow: hidden` or `overflow:auto` (Both are fine!)
4. Now check if the number of '\n' exceeds the number of required rows:
Here is the complete JS structure:

```
$(function() {
  BindHandlers();
  count_of_new_line = 0; /*This variable is global*/
});

function CaretPosition(ctrl) { /*This is to get the current position of cursor*/
  var CaretPos = 0;
  if (document.selection) {
    ctrl.focus();
    var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
    Sel.moveStart('character', -ctrl.value.length);
    CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
  } else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
    CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
  return (CaretPos);
}

function BindHandlers() {
  $('#text_area').on({
    keyup: function(f) {
      var search_value = $(this).val();
      var cursorPosition = CaretPosition(document.getElementById('text_area'));
      var search_value_before_current_cursor = search_value.substr(0, cursorPosition);
      var latest_new_line = search_value_before_current_cursor.lastIndexOf("\n");
      var keycode=f.keyCode;
      if (keycode == 13) {
        count_of_new_line = count_of_new_line + 1;
        if (count_of_new_line > 3) {
          var max_val = search_value.substr(0, latest_new_line);
          $('#text_area').val(max_val);
          search_value = max_val;
          f.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Hope this would help!!